# Side Runner argument for 'binary' not working

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I am trying to specify the binary path to a specific browser location as described on this website https://www.selenium.dev/selenium-ide/docs/en/introduction/command-line-runner.  However the example just does not work.   Running the command (with the proper path)

```
selenium-side-runner -c "goog:chromeOptions.binary='/path/to/non-standard/Chrome/install'"
```

Generates an error:

```
TypeError: Target browser must be a string, but is <undefined>; did you forget to call forBrowser()?
```

Any ideas as to what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this error too! That section of documentation may be outdated. I resolved the error by using [additional params](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium-ide/docs/en/introduction/command-line-runner#advanced-options) instead.

Here is the format:

```
selenium-side-runner --broswerName=chrome --chromeOptions="binary='/path/to/non-standard/Chrome/install'"
```

And here is my example:

```
selenium-side-runner --broswerName=chrome --chromeOptions="binary='C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application'" sitegrammarstorevariable.side
```

Comment: I tried this but it did not work.  Seems to be completely ignoring that parameter since it doesn't even fail when putting in an invalid path.   Could be that this is because I am on Mac instead of Windows.

Comment: Have you also included the .side name? What is the error message now? I am using Windows 10, so perhaps it is an OS-specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have an `Applications` folder in my `$HOME`directory on the Mac and this worked for me:

```
eval selenium-side-runner -c \"browserName=chrome goog:chromeOptions.binary=\'$HOME/Applications/Google/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome\'\" *.side
```

`eval` is used to generalize the command to any user's home directory.

You have to set both the browser name and the path to the binary this way to make it function properly.